# как посчитать сумму элементов в списке используя FOR IN

Tags: python

задача довольно легкая , но ничего не приходить в голову ) 
есть список [ 4, 5 , 4, 5 ,4 ,5 ]
как посчитать сумму всех этих элементов не используя 'sum'
работать нужно с for .. in ..:
заранее благодарен вам за помощь

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
massive = [4, 5 , 4, 5 ,4 ,5]
sum = 0
for i in massive:
    sum += i
print(sum)
```

Это должно сработать

Comment: предлагаю теперь проверить правильность решения воспользовавшись встроенной функцией `sum()` --> `print(sum(massive))` ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
l1 = [1, 99, 57896, 21, 35, 176]

res = 0
for i in l1:
    res += i

print(res)
```